# How to deployment MERN App using render and netlify?

Tags: deployment, mern, netlify, render.com

I have git repository called password-reset. Inside client and server folders are there. client and server have the respective codes. I want to deploy client folder on netlify and server folder on render.com. How to deploy?

I tried this but, it got failed on render.com. Also, It default chooses the client folder to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

I can only really speak to the Netlify portion of your question, but it is likely that you'll want to reverse proxy from Netlify to render.com to stitch the server/client together, while avoiding CORS issues (since netlify will contact render with its own hostname, but allow clients to contact your main domain hosted on netlify transparently).  This is the feature you'd configure on Netlify to do so:  https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/rewrites-proxies/#proxy-to-another-service